# Retrieve device Gmail accounts

Tags: android, gmail, accountmanager

I am trying to get the all accounts info which are configured in my Gmail application, like, username, email address, etc.

I am using the below code -

```
public ArrayList<String> GET_EMAIL_ADDRESSES() {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(FeedbackFragment.this.getActivity()).getAccounts();

    if (accounts == null) {
        Toast.makeText(FeedbackFragment.this.getActivity(),
                "Cannot access email accounts database",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    if (accounts.length <= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(FeedbackFragment.this.getActivity(),
                "No accounts found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    for (Account account : accounts){
        names.add(account.name);
        Toast.makeText(FeedbackFragment.this.getActivity(),account.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return names;
}
```

But it does no retrieves any info even I have configured multiple accounts and always returns the message `"No accounts found"`.

Is anything wrong in my code? Does anyone have any idea how to rectify this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` ?

Comment: @bbedward - Yes.. I have added this permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.